# Where and how to show ajax loading picture

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

In left menu bar i am having two links about and messages while clicking on messages it is fetching user message page from server it is working properly.
I want to show some picture as loading symbol to user, where to put that code i didn't get it.
I am using following ajax code to fetch message page from server

```
 function getMessages(id)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (typeof xmlhttp == "undefined")
        {
            ContentDiv.innerHTML="<h1>XMLHttp cannot be created!</h1>";
        }
        else{

            var query='message?id='+id;
            xmlhttp.open("GET",query,true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("profile-detail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Call the function, showing our loading message when you just get into your function. And function that hides that message in onreadystatechange handler function.

Comment: Just curious: Any reason you're not using a Javascript library like Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Assume you have in you page

```
<img id="ajaxImageCtrl" src="path/ajax.gif" />
```

2 Put this line just after `var xmlhttp;`

```
document.getElementById("ajaxImageCtrl").style.display = 'block'
```

3 Put this line

```
document.getElementById("ajaxImageCtrl").style.display = 'none';
```

after

```
 document.getElementById("profile-detail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I hope this will do the job